# Blender 2.93: the Python dependencies (Scipy, geomdll and more) and Sverchok addon don't work in my Windows pc

Tags: python, add-on, installation, sverchok

I had [Sverchok](https://nortikin.github.io/sverchok) and all of its dependencies working fine on Blender 2.92. Now I installed Blender 2.93 but it recognize only the pip and [cython](https://cython.org/) dependencies. Some hint?

Comment: Have yo utried installing the latest versions ? There has been some changes in the API in 2.93

Answer (score 1):

After a clean install I had success with some other dependencies. But I saw that Blender now has the Python 3.9 while Freecad, open3d and some other have Python 3.8 or lower. So Blender doesn't accept them.